# Alter dataframe via groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to apply an operation to a dataframe on subsets of the same date separately. So what I tried is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1), 'b':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1)}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-08',freq='1H'))

print(df)


                      a   b
2020-01-01 00:00:00  27  47
2020-01-01 01:00:00  46  44
2020-01-01 02:00:00  13  52
2020-01-01 03:00:00  49  56
2020-01-01 04:00:00  78  87
...                  ..  ..
2020-01-07 20:00:00  34   4
2020-01-07 21:00:00  99  71
2020-01-07 22:00:00   6  14
2020-01-07 23:00:00  87  97
2020-01-08 00:00:00  92  64


def example_function(df):
    df.loc['a'] = df.loc[:,'b'].sum()

df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: example_function(x))
```

What I was hoping was that the dataframe would thereby be modified, however this is not the case. Is it anyhow possible to access the 'parent dataframe' through a groupby() operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining the answers of 'jrdzha' and '89f3a1c' I found the answer now. I have to return the df as a whole within the function and in the end assign the group object to df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1), 'b':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1)}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-08',freq='1H'))

print(df)


def example_function(df):
    df.loc[:,'b'].sum()
    return df

df = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: example_function(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that `example_function` doesn't return anything.

The groupby function produces a group of dataframes. Then calling apply on top of this passes each dataframe as `x` to your lambda function. But you lambda function doesn't return anything (thereby returning None). So you are essentially converting your group of dataframes to a group of Nones, which is just an empty dataframe.

Try this instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1), 'b':np.random.randint(0,100,24*7+1)}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-08',freq='1H'))

print(df)


def example_function(df):
    return df.loc[:,'b'].sum()

result = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: example_function(x))
```

> What I was hoping was that the dataframe would thereby be modified, however this is not the case. Is it anyhow possible to access the 'parent dataframe' through a groupby() operation?

Modifying in place is counter to how pandas dataframes typically work. To get the behavior you want, instead of assigning the last line to `result`, you can assign it back to `df`.

Comment: Okay, that's not exactly the behaviour I wanted, I tried this before. Like this I just get a Series back whereas I actually wanted to modifiy the parent dataframe. But I guess it simply isn't possible since the groupby object creates copies of the parent dataframe.

Comment: This is an optimization feature of pandas. However, you may be able to set the "in_place" flag on some operations. Is there a specific reason you need to have it work in place?

Comment: In place is not crucial but that I get the whole dataframe and not just a single column (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

> What I was hoping was that the dataframe would thereby be modified

If you  want this, you can assign the result to the original df

```py
df = df.groupby()...
```

If this was default behaviour, I think it would be a little tedious, since you may want to perform different types of analysis without grouping by the original df.

Edit: add some code to prove my point in the comments.

```py
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: example_function(x))
>>> [empty return]

type(df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: example_function(x)))
>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.a + x.b)
df

2020-01-01  2020-01-01 00:00:00     48
            2020-01-01 01:00:00     45
            2020-01-01 02:00:00     88
            2020-01-01 03:00:00     88
            2020-01-01 04:00:00     91
                                  ... 
2020-01-07  2020-01-07 20:00:00    132
            2020-01-07 21:00:00     81
            2020-01-07 22:00:00     89
            2020-01-07 23:00:00    103
2020-01-08  2020-01-08 00:00:00     72
Length: 169, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why exactly? What doesn't work as you're expecting (I think) is the groupby() + apply(). It returns nothing (it returns an empty dataframe). I'm not sure I correctly understand the intended output of the example function, but if you `apply(lambda x: x.a + x.b)`, you get some actual output which can be assigned without problems to the original variable `df`.